# Codeigniter+default method when parameter is present

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have one issue regarding controllers and methods in Codeigniter 3.
Basically, I have a controller `controller` and the multiple methods (functions)
So, when I call `admin/controller` I will see the `index` method and when I choose `admin/controller/doStuff` then the other method is going to be launched

But, I want to achieve the following:
`admin/controller/1` should point to `admin/controller/index/1`

I have tried to solve this issue with:

```
function _remap($param) {
    $this->index($param);
}
```

It solves my request for index part but it will redirect all methods to index method..
Anyone has a better idea than mine?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 function _remap($method,$args)
{
    if (method_exists($this, $method)) {
        /**
         * Call the method
         */
        $this->$method($args);
    }else {
        /**
         * Otherwise pass $method to index() as an argument
         */
        $this->index($method,$args);
    }
}
```

Comment: The error I am getting is: Undefined variable: method. I guess the $method should be one of the methods from controller, but there should be a dynamic way.. without specifying the method here..

Comment: please change $this->$method to $this->$args. It's working if coded like that. Thank you!

Comment: One more issue, if I use $this->$args, the parameters are lost (admin/controller/dostuff/1)

Comment: But still doesn't work.. if I have this call: admin/controller/dostuff/1 I will lose the 1 parameter from the method..

Comment: Again, if no parameter is present, then, the admin/controller/doStuff will not work..